# Extraneous argument label "completion" in call, swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a function, that is returning some array after completion. The function looks like this:

```
func fetchCalendarEvents (completion: (eventArray: [Meeting]) -> Void) -> Void {

    let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()


    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        granted, error in
        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
            print("access granted: \(granted)")
            .......
        completion (eventArray: arrayOfEvents)
    }
        }
        else {
            print("error: access not granted  \(error)")
            completion (eventArray: [])
        }
    })
}
```

When trying to call this function like this, I get the following error:

```
//error in this line: Extraneous argument label "completion" in call:
CalendarController.fetchCalendarEvents(completion:{(eventArray:[Meeting]) -> Void in
        for meeting in eventArray {
            print("Meeting: \(meeting.title)")
        }
    })
```

I tried to wrap my head around completion handlers, and I use this example:
http://alanduncan.me/2014/06/08/Swift-completion-blocks/
However I can not understand what is wrong with this code?

Also, when I remove completion label, I get this:
[image]

Comment: @matt: No, but what do you use instead? I need to fetch calendar events, how do you do it (we support ios8, ios9, just in case)

Comment: Sorry, I was just confused. Early in the morning here!

Comment: haha, no problems :)) I figured the right answer with some tweaking of @Eric D.'s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `data` argument label because your argument label is not named `data` but is named `eventArray`. There's also an error in the `CalendarController.fetchCalendarEvents` call.

After fixes, your code should look like this:

```
func fetchCalendarEvents (completion: (eventArray: [Meeting]) -> Void) -> Void {

    let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { granted, error in
        if granted {
            print("access granted: \(granted)")
            completion(eventArray: arrayOfEvents)
        } else {
            print("error: access not granted  \(error)")
            completion(eventArray: [])
        }
    })
}
```

And:

```
let calController = CalendarController()
calController.fetchCalendarEvents { (eventArray) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: nitpicking: `&& error == nil` will never be reached. If the access is granted the error is always nil

Comment: @EricD. please, see the image in the edited question, I fixed the name of array, and removed the extraneous label, still get error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of @Eric D. the right answer is:

```
let f = CalendarController()
f.fetchCalendarEvents{(eventArray) -> Void in
    ....
}
```

The problem was that I tried apply method to a class, and not a variable of the type of the class. I don't know why, but it only works like this.